# How to create a datastore_query.Order object for ndb Query constructor?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I noticed at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass, there is an optional argument for the ndb.Query constructor that allows you to specify order in the query.  This argument must be of type datastore_query.Order, but I can't seem to find any documentation on this object or how to create it.  What I would like to do is specify a list of Model properties to order by:

```
property_list = [Item.property1, Item.property2]
items = Item.query(orders=Order(property_list))
```

instead of:

```
items = Item.query().order(Item.property1, Item.property2)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a `datastore_query.CompositeOrder` composed of `PropertyOrder`s of the properties in your list. The [source for the Order subclasses](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py) seems to be explained quite well, and you can take a look at what [ndb.Query.order()](http://appengine-ndb-experiment.googlecode.com/hg-history/0.1/ndb/query.py) does to construct them, and do that yourself to get the object to pass to the constructor.

(I can't think of a situation where just using .order() wouldn't be suitable though, and it will be much simpler.)

Comment: I guess I was over-complicating things.  I found I can just use Mode.query().order(*[...]).

Comment: Yes, please just use .order(...).